# Create an index from search results using _reindex API

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, data-storage, elasticsearch-indices

I'am tring to store the results of my search request in new index.
This is my code:

```
POST /_reindex
{ 
  "source": {
    "index": "my_index_name",
    "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "host.hostname": "value_1"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "message": "value_a"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
   "size":3
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "new_test"
  }
}
```

This request is limited to a size of 3. However the size limit is not taken into account. Hence the Post request result is 502 error with this message:

```
{"ok":false,"message":"backend closed connection"}
```

My question is how can i store the result of the request above in a new index in ELasticsearch?
Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the top-level [`max_docs` parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html#docs-reindex-api-request-body) instead of `source.size`:

```
POST /_reindex
{
  "max_docs": 3,
  "source": {
    "index": "my_index_name",
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "must": [
          {
            "match": {
              "host.hostname": "value_1"
            }
          },
          {
            "match": {
              "message": "value_a"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "new_test"
  }
}
```

Comment: You are faster then lightning !! I didnt refresh page so not aware that you have already posted answer. SO should implement functionality to show popup or notification when someone writing answer on question similar to what discuss.elastic have.

Comment: HAHA you made my day  Glad to help 

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `max_docs` param to your request.

```json
POST _reindex
{
  "max_docs": 1,
  "source": {
    "index": "my-index-000001"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "my-new-index-000001"
  }
}
```

`size` param is for number of documents to index per batch.

> By default _reindex uses scroll batches of 1000. You can change the
> batch size with the size field in the source element

Comment: @saad great to know that it helps you !! you can mark as solution if it is helps you.

Comment: i'am a new contributor :(